# OpenShift / Docker thin provisioning

Tags: docker, lvm, openshift-origin, thin-provisioning

I've been looking at OpenShift Origin documentation and tutorials for the past two days and I have a few questions if you guys can help me;

For Docker’s thin provisioning configuration for production environments using direct-lvm the most common approach (not to say all I encountered) is to use a separate physical drive setup with LVM for the volume group. Is there a problem with using one partitioned hard drive shared between the root system? This comes as some of the machines we use (which are rented) come with large hard drives on the initial configuration, and it’s easier to partition one big drive and mirror it than doing this with several, no? Are there disadvantages?

Two machines have been configured with initial disk setup, one has boot + root and swap, where root and swap sit on LVM on a volume group /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3 is the docker volume group, and the other has boot, root and swap as separate devices and only the remaining space is a volume group. Are both approaches correct or are there considerations to have in mind regarding these setups?

Comment: This is a good question. But, if you lease servers, you're limited to whatever hardware configurations the provider will give you. Also keep in mind that the docs are a bit out of date; newly installed OpenShift clusters will have overlay2 as the default storage driver, not LVM thin provisioning.

Comment: From [docker official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/) - In addition, Docker does not recommend any configuration that requires you to disable security features of your operating system, such as the need to disable selinux if you use the overlay or overlay2 driver on CentOS. - I am able to choose whatever hardware configuration I want on my leased servers, I mentioned the out of the box solution that includes large drives that are suitable upon partitioning.

Comment: You do not need to disable SELinux if you use overlay2. But you do need to have CentOS 7.4 or later. It did not work with previous versions, which is probably why that note is there.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the disadvantage that your docker data will share a drive with your operating system there won't be any disadvantages when you partition the drive as you suggested.

Both of your approaches are correct. I'd prefer the variant with two volume groups because it gives you more flexiblility for your OS than plain partitions, but that decision is totally up to you.